# How to "map" Blogger blog to custom domain without dates (year/month)?

Tags: blogger

I have a Blogger blog with custom domain.

**Situation:** Blogger blog url post - http://mydomainname.com/YEAR/MONTH/posttitle.

Query: Is there a way to get rid of the /YEAR/MONTH and make my Blogger blog url post - http://mydomainname.com/posttitle?

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Try making a suggestion at the official google product forums under "suggestions" category.

I made it 3 years back.Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no option to get a permalink like that for blogger posts however you could get a direct link for  static pages { yourdomain.com/p/thepage  }
But number of static pages is limited to 20 and there are some tricks that may help you overcome this limitation. Eventhough I haven't tried it personally it is worth to give it a try if you want more than 20 static pages.
http://www.hackinguniversity.in/2013/11/unlimited-pages-blogger.html

I would also recommend you to file a suggestion to blogger to include this feature. In the mean time this trick may help you.